# UTF8 letters issue in latin mysql database

Tags: mysql, utf-8, latin1

I have latin1 MySQL database and it is too late to convert it to utf8.
When I search for text that contains (French letter for example), I get same result with English letter. 
Example: when I search for "tést", I get "test" from MySQL.
How can I avoid this?
Thank you.

Comment: Please a [mcve]. Make sure to include the code you used to store data and the code you used to query the data.

Answer (score 0):

The `COLLATION latin1_general_ci` will find `test` when searching for `tést`.  Since that is probably what your collation is (let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`), that is no efficient way to avoid getting `test`.

If all you have is Western European characters, `utf8` is not a critical goal.

To change the table `foo` to that collation:

```
ALTER TABLE foo CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

Since it will involve copying the entire table, it will take some time.